RMAN - keep until and control_file_record_keep_time
Should I adjust control_file_record_keep_time to match the KEEP UNTIL value in my RMAN script?
Here's my monthly backup script:
RUN
{
    BACKUP AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET FULL 
    FORMAT 'FULL_MONTHLY_%T_%d_%U' 
    TAG 'FULL_MONTHLY_BACKUP' 
    DATABASE INCLUDE CURRENT CONTROLFILE 
    KEEP UNTIL TIME 'SYSDATE+365'
    plus ARCHIVELOG 
    FORMAT 'FULL_MONTHLY_%T_ARCH_%d_%U' 
    TAG 'FULL_MONTHLY_BACKUP' 
    KEEP UNTIL TIME 'SYSDATE+365';
}

This script is executed monthly, and I want to retain each monthly backup for 12 months.
Should I also set control_file_record_keep_time to 365 days?

do you use a recovery catalog?

@miracle173 no, only controlfile.


Should I adjust control_file_record_keep_time to match the KEEP UNTIL value in my RMAN script?

No you shouldn't. This parameter force control file to keep track of your backups for year. However it's not required since you attach your control backup to database backup so to perform restore you can restore the controlfile from the backup and it 'knows' about database and archivelog backups.
I'd recommend to test it to make sure the backup of controlfile is the last thing in the set. Another option is explicit controlfile backup after archivelog backups.
If you really want to keep track of your backups for year I'd rather save it in RMAN catalog and not in controlfile.

Why do you think that one shouldn't adjust the  control_file_record_keep_time to match the KEEP UNTIL value in the RMAN script? Can you show the text  in the manualsfrom which this can be derived?

because I don't want history of all backups for the year be copied every time controlfile backup happened. For long time storage I'd rather use RMAN catalog.

but we do not know if OP uses a catalog and you do not mention a catalog in your post.. If he doesn't  then the information about the older backups may be overwritten if the control_file_record_keep_time parameter is to small.

I cannot imagine scenario with keeping backup history for year could be beneficial except: using existing controlfile restore full backup year old and apply  archive logs for months of work. I guess OP want just to restore a database copy from this particular set: restore controlfile from the set, restore datafiles, recover database with archivelogs. For this scenario a year old backup history is not required.

"I cannot imagine..." I think it is not relevant if you can imagine if the backup must be kept for a year. The OP apperently wants to keep the backup for a year. And answering his question "Should I adjust control_file_record_keep_time" by "no" is simply wrong if you don not know more about his backup, e.g. if he uses a catalog. With this advice he or any other user hos follows your advice  may loose backup records from the confrol file. So this answer should be removed.
..."

In my opinion, one should never trust completely what others tell about backup. Such things need to be checked by yourself.
Create test database,
set control_file_record_keep_time=2,
make KEEP UNTIL backup,
some backups and archivelogs everyday,
see when they are gone from control file.
By the way, probably there are too many words in your script. I mean "plus ARCHIVELOG ...". Do you really need backup of all archivelogs on disk, made before your KEEP backup? Probably, not.
The command below will create a backup of datafiles, necessary archivelogs for this backup, controlfile and spfile backup. And do not trust me, do the recover.
RUN
{
    BACKUP AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET 
    FORMAT 'FULL_MONTHLY_%T_%d_%U' 
    TAG 'FULL_MONTHLY_BACKUP' 
    DATABASE 
    KEEP UNTIL TIME 'SYSDATE+366' ;
}

This is the link to the documentation:
backup KEEP option where Orace says:

If the database is open during the backup, then RMAN automatically generates and backs up the archived redo log files needed to make the database backup consistent


this will not work. the command will create the necessary archive  logs for the backup by doing a logswitch before and after the backup f the datafiles start but it will not backup the archive logs. wo you will not have a useful backu

It's just works, @miracle173 . At list since 11g in the same way. This type of backup makes log switch, so, as I wrote before, put necessary archivelogs into backup. The keep option is useful not only for long-term backups, but also for creating self-contained, standalone backup. Added link to the docs in the answer. Try it, you will like it )

you are right. The keep option will cause that all necessary archives are backed up, too. That was new to me.
